# SQL Jobs logging only 2 days

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, logs

When I righ click the job + view history, I can only see 2 days of logs. I'm sure this is a really noob question but I can't find the answer.

[image]

I've been changing values but with no success. The same config I have in this server, I have in other servers.

---

Comment: The size of the history is spread over all the Agent jobs. So you'll get 1000 rows total for all jobs, with 100 rows possible only if there is space in that 1000

Comment: Thanks @MarkSinkinson. So if I disable "Limit size of history...", I'll be able to store all logs?( obviously this is not a good pratice, I think )

Comment: I believe so, but why would you need to? You can always extract what is useful from the logs via a script to persist it in another table

Comment: The problem here is...there was some error in one of our jobs. But I can see the log because the error occured OCT 31, and I have the log only for nov 1 and nov 2. I wouls love to see the OCT 31 log.I don't have MSDB backups. I think I will need one.

Comment: Maybe for the future, create a nightly procedure that extracts all your failures into a persisted table

Comment: The other option, unchecked in your screenshot, is what you're probably looking for. Set a retention window and stick to it.

Comment: I'm with @spaghettidba, Don't mess with total amount across all jobs or the max number per job.  Just set it to a flat 4 weeks and call it a day.

Comment: Strange...When I mark "delete logs older than..." and click ok, nothing happens. The window close, but when I re-open it , it's still not marked. Should I restart SQL Agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very common to miss the job history for quite a jobs where you are running large number of SQL agent jobs performing various task , for e.g lets say backup involving diff (say 4 hours daily) and log backups (say every 15 or 30 mins) and in addition the no of databases are also large in number than its obvious that default setting for max rows per job which is 100 in you're case wont be good and history would not be saved for many jobs and hence you are not able to view the history.

You can run below script to find the no of executions occurring for the jobs which will give you an overview of whats happening out there with history:

```
SELECT j.name, COUNT(*) Executions
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
ON j.job_id = h.job_id
GROUP BY j.name
ORDER BY Executions DESC
```

You will notice that the default setting is to only keep the last 1,000 history records for all the SQL Agent Jobs. The SQL Agent will also only keep 100 history records for a single job.

Therefore as mentioned earlier in comments and answer you can Disable the limit size of job history log and utilize sp_purge_jobhistory to purge as needed to meet your storage and business requirements for maintaining agent job history.

OR you can use T-SQL to disable this default setting and schedule an SQL agent job to clear the job history, depending upon the no of jobs and their executions:

To disable run below:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties 
 @jobhistory_max_rows=-1,
 @jobhistory_max_rows_per_job=-1
Go
```

Now, create a new SQL job to run once a day and put in this T-SQL code. In this example I will only keep the job history for the last 10 days.

```
DECLARE @OldestDate datetime
SET @OldestDate = GETDATE()-10
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_purge_jobhistory @oldest_date=@OldestDate@
```

Also, say for a job like in my case where we have T-log backups running every 15 mins, so in this case we only require job history for 2 days to troubleshoot.To make this customization you just need to add another step to a job as follows.

```
DECLARE @OldestDate datetime
DECLARE @JobName varchar(256)
-- Keep Last 2 days
SET @OldestDate = GETDATE()-2
SET @JobName = 'LOG Backup ABC'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_purge_jobhistory 
 @job_name=@JobName, 
 @oldest_date=@OldestDate
```

This should do good for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should either remove the checkbox to limit the size of the job history or increase it.  One of your maintenance steps should be to run the sp_purge_jobhistory [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175044.aspx) command to remove job history older than your retention period.

The "Remove Agent History" checkbox does this behind the scenes but is NOT an automated process that removes history older than the time period specified.  It's really badly named and placed.

If you have lots of jobs or a few jobs that run very often then you will quickly use up 1000 logs of job executions.  As mentioned in the comments, another solution is to archive the contents of the sysjobhistory table.